# How to write mysql php errors to a text file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following PHP code that creates a mysql connection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$mysql_server", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_pw", "$mysql_db");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In the event the connection is not made, how can I write the error to a text file on my server?

Comment: [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function in php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$mysql_server", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_pw", "$mysql_db");
if (!$con)
{
    error_log(mysqli_error($con) . "\n", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
}
```

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry. It's typing mistake :-)

Comment: It's still wrong. The correct one would be: `mysqli_error($conn)` where `$conn` is a link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`.

Comment: @AmalMurali. Thanks again. I was busy in another tutorial. So I couldn't notice. Thanks a lot.